# Paperclip multiple resize conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm working on an app that has multiple conditions for image uploads. The conditions are that it must be *at least* 350px high, and have a fixed width of 500px.

I've been playing around with it for a while, and I've come up with a way using `convert_options`:

```
:convert_options => {
    :medium => "-resize 500x350^ -crop 500x1000+0+0 +repage"
}
```

I could set the height parameter in the crop to anything, but 1000 is a suitable number.

This works, however I have a feeling I overcomplicated it and I'm curious to see if it would be possible to do this with a single parameter in `:styles` using flags. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the size dimentions of an image with conditions in a procedure within `:styles` attribute.

For details check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656939/ror-paperclip-how-to-set-minimal-width-of-an-attachement) SO post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I feel that's even more complicated than just using `:convert_options`

Comment: yes its like that but in context of doing it within `styles` attribute, that is the one you can do that way.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the explanation. Is there any benefit either way?

Comment: The code readability is more in the way I suggested you because it is clear in the procedure what you are trying to accomplish (in resize conditions) although it seems to be more code.